# Sending goals to the navigation stack

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what do you have to do in order to achieve, the navigation of a knowed map?.

I want to make a little server, that order the robot to move using a list of points. How can I say: use the `foo` map as a reference to the origin and  send a pose/goal with the little server to the navigation stack.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214633/sending-goals-to-the-navigation-stack/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Here is a tutorial for [navigating a known map](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/indigo/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) and one for [sending navigation goals](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals). These should explain how to do what you're asking. Also, there are plenty of other [navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation#Tutorials) that might help you along your way.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1